# Filter wp_login function correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope you're doing good.

I'm trying to add a custom validation to the WP_login auth. I'm doing this:

```
public function logoutIfInactive($user_login)
{
    $user = get_user_by('login',$user_login);

    if ( get_user_meta($user->ID, '_architect_active', 1) != 1 )
    {
        return new WP_Error( 'architect_disabled', 'Your architect account is pending of review' );
    }
}
```

And the hook:

```
add_filter('wp_login', [$this, 'logoutIfInactive'], -1);
```

The hook is working, but I can't get the WP_Error to work. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I should hook another function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `wp_login` is an action hook that fires after the users is completely logged in. You need to use something in the middle of login process, best hook for this is `wp_authenticate_user`

```
public function logoutIfInactive($user)
{
    if ( get_user_meta($user->ID, '_architect_active', 1) != 1 )
    {
        new WP_Error( 'architect_disabled', 'Your architect account is pending of review' );
    }
    return $user;
}
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', [$this, 'logoutIfInactive'], 10);
```